# Tkinter GUI function to run a function off of an opened file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on a GUI that has three buttons:

- One to point to and open a .txt file.
- One to compile (run a function) off that opened file.
- One to save as a new file elsewhere.

How can I adjust the code for my `split_lines()` function to read off the opened file in `open_file()` function?

`split_lines` was taken from another program that runs without a GUI.

```
def open_file(): # Defines the function that's run off the open button.
  filepath = askopenfilename(
      filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
  if not filepath:
      return
  txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
  with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
      text = input_file.read()
      txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
  window.title(f"Simple Text Editor - {filepath}")

cleaned_data = [] # Defines the function that compiles the information.
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '^[0-9.]+$'):
  for line in lines:
    tokens = line.split(delimiter)
    tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
    clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    cleaned_data.append(clean_list)
    print(clean_list)

split_lines(text, "/") # Tried reading "text" but this doesn't work.
```

How can I adjust this to read the file that was opened in `open_file()`?

Comment: You can use the built-in [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function to execute source code, however it is very unsafe to use it with user input.

Comment: In `split_lines()` I had originally used the .txt file input as `lines` which was a .txt file with my info. I need to change that function to read from the .txt file the `open_file()` is pointing too. Does that make sense?

Comment: The file in `open_file()` gets closed at the end of the `with` clause. If you want to execute its contents you will need to (re)open that file, read its contents into a string, then `exec()` that.

Comment: Yes I'd like to (re)open that file then run the function, could you point me in the right direction to read the contents into a new string, then `exec()` that ?

Comment: Something along the line lines of: `with open(filepath) as file:`, then (indented) `exec(file.read())`.